# SQL ESCAPE with multiple LIKE conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to specify the same escape character for multiple `LIKE` conditions. Which is correct?

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column1] LIKE 'value1!%'            AND [column2] LIKE 'value2!%' ESCAPE '!'
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column1] LIKE 'value1!%' ESCAPE '!' AND [column2] LIKE 'value2!%' ESCAPE '!'
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column1] LIKE 'value1!%' ESCAPE '!' AND [column2] LIKE 'value2!%'
```

Or something else entirely?

Comment: What character are you trying to escape? You are currently escaping the % wilcard, is that what you intend to do ?

Comment: THe second is correct.  The `escape` keyword is part of the `like` syntax.  Of course, you could just try them and see that that one works.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, they all validated correctly, and I was getting myself confused trying to come up with a scenario that would yield a distinct result for each query. Thanks for the explanation! Jaco, yes that's my intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Second item is correct:

```
SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [column1] LIKE 'value1!%' ESCAPE '!' AND [column2] LIKE 'value2!%' ESCAPE '!'
```

Comment: Thank you, @BrianAtkins. For my own reference, is there a source for that? I was unable to find any explanation on the Microsoft Developer Network past the basic `match_expression [ NOT ] LIKE pattern [ ESCAPE escape_character ]` syntax (which is why I tried SO).

Comment: This is the best I could find quickly.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378045%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396